# Unable to access the remote machine using SSH

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

**Expected**:I would like to access my remote machine through SSH.

**Observed**: Connection time out error throws on executing the below command in my local machine

ssh admin@myname.domain.com(I have given dummy domain here)

**Details**:

Local machine: Peppermint OS.

Remote machine: Ubuntu OS connected directly to Home router.Due to Dynamic IP address issue, I have configured ddclient in my remote machine which I have given below.

```
**ddclient.conf file**:

blacks2@colorgroup:~$ sudo cat /etc/ddclient.conf
# Configuration file for ddclient generated by debconf
#
# /etc/ddclient.conf
protocol=dyndns2
use=web, web=checkip.dyndns.com, web-skip='IP Address'
server=dynupdate.no-ip.com
login=username
password='passwords'
somename.domain.com
```

**After configuring, I have confirmed the ddclient has installed correctly by**

```
blacks2@colorgroup:~$ sudo ddclient -daemon=0 -debug -verbose -noquiet
SUCCESS:  somename.domain.com: skipped: IP address was already set to 'IP address'.
```

**Configured router port forwarding setting**

```
    **Application**: SSH
    **External port**: 22
    **Internal port**:22
    **IP address**: 10.1.1.32
```

**SSH works locally for the both machines.**
    I could not access the remote machine through SSH and help needed to resolve.

Thanks and Regards,

Mohan

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your myname.domain.com allows ssh connection thru port 22 by using below command (need nmap rpm)

```
nmap myname.domain.com -p 22
```

If the returned status is "filtered". It means the port is blocked. Then you can try to allow it on your myname.domain.com firewall first (in case your server is a linux)

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

After that, rerun the nmap command. If it is still "filtered", the port is blocking by a middle firewall. In that case, you need to contact your firewall administrator.